# highcharts highlight selected point (png)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Is there a way to highlight point on click when my point is a png?
I am trying to put red color around my png, I don't want to change the png to "highlighted" one, but only to add css to my png point.

Comment: Can you make a live example, e.g. on jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shahard/6jesdckc/40/

here you can see each point represented by icon, I want to highlight it on click by using highcharts configuration. (without creating special highlighted icon)

Answer (score 2):

You can use renderer object to create desired SVG path:

```
// inside point's click event callback function
var borderWidth = 5; // in px

this.series.chart.renderer.circle(this.series.xAxis.toPixels(this.x), 
this.series.yAxis.toPixels(this.y), marker.width / 2 + borderWidth).attr({fill: 'red'}).add();
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/as9kqwc0/

API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.circle

Comment: Hi this is exactly what we want, thank you very much.
 Is there an easy way to clear the red circle after selecting another point?

Comment: Yes. I store it in the 'selectedpointBorder' variable. Before I render a new one I check if the border already exist and if it's true I destroy it. I updated my fiddle whit this code.